# I had an epiphany about what my life may/might actually be like a few years from now, if i did't set my priorities set

Tags: tense, grammaticality

> (1) I had an epiphany about what my life **might** actually be like a few years from now, if I **don't** set my priorities.
>
> (2) I had an epiphany about what my life **may** actually be like a few years from now, if I **don't** set my priorities.
>
> (3) I had an epiphany about what my life **might** actually be like a few years from now, if I **didn't** set my priorities.

Let's say the epiphany the speaker is talking about, the speaker had earlier today. Having said that, which of the above sentences are grammatically correct, and what's the difference in their meaning?

Comment: The first one is correct, since the first clause is referring to the future, and the second clause refers to the present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[may](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/may) and [might](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/might) express probability. [Most people](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/may-versus-might) agree that something that **may** happen is more probable than something that **might** happen. If you really want to push the limits of probability, you can say **just might** happen.

If you want to talk about a situation that could occur, you use **don't**: for example,

> If you don't stop humming that song, I shall scream!

If you want to talk about a hypothetical situation- one that could never happen, you use **didn't**: you might say:

> I the sun didn't come up tomorrow, it would be very dark all day.

So, the two sentences with **don't** are both valid. For **may** or **might**, the choice would depend on how scary your epiphany was. If it involved dying in the gutter of a heroin overdose, **might** is the right word. If it involved not having money for cigarettes, **may** is the right word.