# What is the difference for sentences

Tags: modal-verbs

> Sentence A: I am ready for whatever may happen.

> Sentence B: I am ready for whatever might happen.

I don’t understand the difference.
Is it true that both sentences convey the same meaning? Please explain.

Comment: In simple terms, yes, they have the same meaning.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You may well be right, but for some reason, I seem to think there is a very subtle difference between the two. I cannot seem to quite put my finger on it. I thought somebody here might be able to "quantify" the difference between the two sentences in a very precise way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Might" vs. "may". What's the difference?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/386/might-vs-may-whats-the-difference) Also [Difference between might not and may not](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/276902/difference-between-might-not-and-may-not) and [I had an epiphany about what my life may/might actually be like a few years from now, if i did't set my priorities set](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/86372/), among others.

Comment: I think there is a subtle difference. In the case of these two sentences, "might" suggests a more practical immediacy and is somewhat time-dependent. "May" seems a bit more philosophical, time and context-independent, and accepting. 

I would be more likely to use the "might" sentence if I was referring to being prepared for a possible layoff, or wildfire season. I would use "may" if I was talking more about my spiritual practice or natural fortitude, and how they allow me to be prepared for whatever life might (heh) bring.

Comment: @HFBrowning Bravo, man! That is so wonderfully put!

Comment: To HFBrowning, Thank you for the trouble you took to answer my question. Your answer confirms my own suspicions about the two sentences, but seeing your answer in black and white adds to my confidence about the correct usage of these two closely related words "may" and "might".